# How could I check a single document against an existing mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose query saved in a variable, then I have a random mongoose document of the same collection, that the query is on. I want to know if my document matches the query. I know I could run the query on the collection and then look if the resulting set contains the document, but I would like to save some performance and run it just on the one document. Is this possible? If it is, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a local query might be possible, I'd suggest you consider doing something like this if a local query isn't possible:

```
Example
   .findOne(existingQuery)
   .where('id').equals(compareTo.id)
   .select('id')
   .exec(function(err, doc) {
      if (!err && doc) {
         console.log('found it!');
      }
   });
```

The document you're comparing has an `_id`. So, above, I've passed the existing query you mentioned, and also added a check for the random document's `_id`. MongoDB should use the index (as you've used the `_id`) and then run your query. It returns as little as possible (rather than the full document).

While this requires that the query executes against the database, it will only check a single document.

Comment: findOne will take a Query object as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK with the existing mongodb tools only, you cannot do this. However, as part of [meteor.js framework](http://www.meteor.com/) they have an in-memory port of a subset of the mongodb interface called [minimongo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/minimongo), including the majority of the query semantics (I believe, this is mostly from reading articles as opposed to direct experience building with these tools). So in theory you could add your document to a 1-document array (in-memory collection) and run against that with minimongo. If you try that and get it working outside of meteor, let me know because it seems handy in general as well as for testing!

One other option which probably doesn't make sense in the grand scheme of things, unless your main collection is truly humongous, but I'll mention just because I believe it to be a valid option to consider, would be to insert your single document into a new (autocreated on insertion by mongodb) temporary collection and query that.